# Can I pass 'this' as an argument when register event listeners to local-DOM children?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

As subject, can I pass 'this' as an argument when register an event listeners to local-DOM children instead of using event.target?

Below code would like to print out the list of files name by passing 'this' as an argument, but the code **doesn't work**

```
<dom-module id="handle-files">
  <template>
    <input type="file" multiple on-change="handleFiles(this.files)">
  </template>
  <script>
      Polymer({
          is: 'handle-files',

              handleFiles: function(files) {
                  console.log(files)
              }
          });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Below code **does work** by using event.target

```
<dom-module id="handle-files">
  <template>
    <input type="file" multiple on-change="handleFiles">
   </template>
   <script>
       Polymer({
           is: 'handle-files',

           handleFiles: function(event) {
               console.log(event.target.files)
           }
       });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about polymer, but *this* is set entirely by how the listener is called. Clearly it isn't being called in the standard way, a hint is the attribute name: *on-change* rather than *onchange*.

Answer (score 0):

you could put an id on your input

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" multiple on-change="handleFiles">
```

and access using

```
this.$.fileInput.files
```

(FYI, this will always be the polymer element)